# How do I switch the components from a character motor to a character controller?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am trying to code some underwater functionality for my Unity game, but I am having trouble switching the CharacterMotor components to the CharacterController ones. This is my code:

```
#pragma strict

var waterLevel : float;
var myParticles : ParticleSystem;
private var isUnderwater : boolean;
private var normalColor : Color;
private var underwaterColor : Color;
private var charcontroller:CharacterController;

function Start () 
    {
        normalColor = new Color (0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        underwaterColor = new Color (0.22f, 0.65f, 0.77f, 0.5f);
        charcontroller = GetComponent(CharacterController);
        myParticles.Stop();
        GameObject.Find("Blob Light Projector").GetComponent(Projector).enabled = false;
    }

function Update () 
    {
            if ((transform.position.y < waterLevel) != isUnderwater) 
            {
                isUnderwater = transform.position.y < waterLevel;
                if (isUnderwater) SetUnderwater ();
                if (!isUnderwater) SetNormal ();
            }

            if(isUnderwater && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
            {
                constantForce.relativeForce = Vector3(0,-200, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                constantForce.relativeForce = Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            }

            if(isUnderwater && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
            {
                constantForce.relativeForce = Vector3(0, 200, 0);
            }
     }

function SetNormal () 
        {
            RenderSettings.fogColor = normalColor;
            RenderSettings.fogDensity = 0.05f;
            GameObject.Find("Blob Light Projector").GetComponent(Projector).enabled = false;
        }

**function SetUnderwater () 
        {
            RenderSettings.fogColor = underwaterColor;
            RenderSettings.fogDensity = 0.08f;
            charcontroller.Move.gravity = 2;
            charcontroller.Move.maxFallSpeed = 5;
            charcontroller.Move.maxForwardSpeed = 4;
            charcontroller.Move.maxSidewaysSpeed = 4;
            myParticles.Play();
            GameObject.Find("Blob Light Projector").GetComponent(Projector).enabled = true;
        }**
```

The bolded code is where the error is coming from. Here is a snapshot of the errors I'm getting: 
[image]

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set properties on CharacterController.Move, which is a function. It doesn't reflect the "movement" property of CharacterMotor.

Check out the [script reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html) and [manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CharacterController.html) to see how to use CharacterController. Specifically, you'll be calling Move with a simple Vector3, and relying on the physics system to take care of the rest.

Comment: So, would it be something like charcontroller.Move { gravity=2; } ?

Comment: No, like I said, Move is a function, and only takes a vector for how much you want to move it. I really highly recommend you look at the CharacterController reference, so you understand what you're dealing with. You'll see that there is no "gravity" implementation at all, so things like gravity and lateral resistance due to water...you're going to need to add all of those by yourself, into your component.